# Is paying more gems a better gamble?

Tags: castle-clash

In Castle Clash, you can buy a random hero with 150 gems or three random heroes with 450 gems. Is there any benefit to saving up 450 gems rather than paying 150 gems three times? Perhaps better odds at getting higher class heroes?

Castle Clash's [website](http://www.castleclash.net/how-to-get-castle-clash-heroes/) indicates that paying gems for heroes gives you better odds than paying honor badges, but doesn't really mention any difference between the two ways to pay gems.

Comment: I've bought 12 heroes using the 450 gem method at an average cost in shards of 451 per hero. I've bought 4 heroes using the 150 gem method at an average cost in shards of 825 per hero. So far, I believe that the two are equivalent and that a single outlier has skewed my current results toward the 150 gem method. More research necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference in probability.

The chances of you getting a legendary remains the same. For example if you roll for 1 hero, you have a 5% chance of getting a legendary. If you roll for 3 heroes at the same time, each hero has a 5% of being legendary.

Comment: This matches with my experience. I guess the 450-gem option is just a convenience for buying multiple at a time.

Comment: @ken.ganong Yes, you are absolutely right.